# How to rotate a SKPhysicsBody in SpriteKit with Swift

Tags: swift, rotation, sprite-kit, collision, skphysicsbody

I am trying to make a brick breaking game with SpriteKit in Swift. To make the paddle I am trying to make it so that there are two SKPhysicBody, one for each half. To control the angle of which the ball bounces off the paddle, I want to rotate the physics body. I tried to use applyAngularImpulse or just applyForce, but they did not work. Is there a way to rotate the physics body??

Comment: Could you post the code with the applyForce and applyAngularImpulse methods you have already tried?

Comment: If applyAngular impulse is not working, try using applyTorque in the update method.

Comment: You can't set the rotation of a physics body. You can however set the rotation of the node that the physics body is attached to.
So what you can do is make a dedicated node for your physics body. This node will be invisible, it will only exist for you to rotate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set the rotation of a physics body. You can however set the rotation of the node that the physics body is attached to. So what you can do is make a dedicated node for your physics body. This node will be invisible, it will only exist for you to rotate.